# Processing dataframe column via str_split using values in another column R

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization

I'm wondering if there's a nicer way to address the following problem

I have a dataframe with the following example structure:

| Split_key | label | sub_label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A_B_C | 7 | "" |
| A_B_C | 7 | "" |
| A_B_C | 8 | "" |
| A_B_C | 8 | "" |
| A_B_C | 10 | "" |
| A_B_C | 10 | "" |
| D_E_F | 2 | "" |
| D_E_F | 7 | "" |
| D_E_F | 15 | "" |
| G_H_I | 1 | "" |
| G_H_I | 2 | "" |
| G_H_I | 3 | "" |

I wish to populate sub_label with a value that corresponds to splitting the value in Split_key on the "_" character and grabs the correct element based on label. The correct element is the index of the value in label in the unique sorted array of labels that share the same value in Split_key.

The correct end result is shown here.

| Split_key | label | sub_label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A_B_C | 7 | A |
| A_B_C | 7 | A |
| A_B_C | 8 | B |
| A_B_C | 8 | B |
| A_B_C | 10 | C |
| A_B_C | 10 | C |
| D_E_F | 2 | D |
| D_E_F | 7 | E |
| D_E_F | 15 | F |
| G_H_I | 1 | G |
| G_H_I | 2 | H |
| G_H_I | 3 | I |

Here is my initial attempt.

```
for (row_n in 1:nrow(df)){
  df%>%filter(`Split_key`==df[row_n,"Split_key"][[1]])->duplicates
  shift<-which(sort(unique(duplicates$label))==df[row_n,"label"][[1]])
  df[row_n,"sub_label"]<-str_split(df[row_n,"Split_key"],"_")[[1]][shift]
}
```

This solution works but is slower than I'd like with large dataframes. Is there a way to accomplish this task without using a for loop?

Comment: Could you detail further how `label` is used to identify which component to extract from `Split key`?

Comment: I can just about guarantee that there is a better way to extract this than a `for` loop iterating over every row. But ... taking `"A_B_C"` and `7` and somehow coming up with `"A"` is lost on me.

Comment: @r2evans I think the answer lies in this paragraph: _"I wish to populate `sub_label` with a value that corresponds to splitting the value in `Split_key` on the `"_"` character and grabs the correct element based on `label`. The correct element is the index of the value in `label` in the unique sorted array of `label`s that share the same value in `Split_key`."_

Comment: That is ... really obscure ...

Comment: @r2evans So for example: there are 6 rows with a `Split key` of `"A_B_C"`, and the set of their `labels` is `c(7, 7, 8, 8, 10, 10)`.  Since the sorted uniques of this set are `c(7, 8, 10)`, here is the set of indices therein that correspond to the original `label`s: `c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)`.  These indicate the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd components of `"A_B_C"` when split: `c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C")`.

Comment: I think I get it, @Greg, I really appreciate you sticking with me there ... I think my answer reflects what you're saying there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be faster than a loop:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(Split_key) %>%
  mutate(sub_label2 = strsplit(Split_key[1], "_")[[1]][ match(label, sort(unique(label))) ]) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 12 x 4
#    Split_key label sub_label sub_label2
#    <chr>     <int> <chr>     <chr>     
#  1 A_B_C         7 A         A         
#  2 A_B_C         7 A         A         
#  3 A_B_C         8 B         B         
#  4 A_B_C         8 B         B         
#  5 A_B_C        10 C         C         
#  6 A_B_C        10 C         C         
#  7 D_E_F         2 D         D         
#  8 D_E_F         7 E         E         
#  9 D_E_F        15 F         F         
# 10 G_H_I         1 G         G         
# 11 G_H_I         2 H         H         
# 12 G_H_I         3 I         I
```

If there are fewer elements encoded within `Split_key` than there are distinct values in `sub_label`, then you will get `NA` for those rows.

Walk-through:

- `group_by(Split_key)`: since we need to track unique `label` for each `Split_key`, then we group in this field and simplify processing to one group at a time;
- `strsplit(Split_key[1], ")")[[1]]`: within a particular group, we only need one of the `Split_key` values to split, not all of them (since they are all identical), this results internally in a vector such as `c("A", "B", "C")` in the first group;
- `match(label, sort(unique(label)))` translates (first group) to `match(c(7,7,8,8,10,10), c(7,8,10))` which translates to `c(1,1,2,2,3,3)`; this is used to index on the vector `c("A","B","C")` from the previous bullet

Comment: Nice job vectorizing the solution (insofar as possible)!

Comment: Very elegant solution, I was unaware of the group and ungroup functionality combo that really makes this possible. Thanks!

Comment: I agree: understanding how to use grouping in data-processing is a huge enabler; it's no coincidence that all three answers use it.

Comment: Does anyone know if there's a similar functionality/solution in python pandas?

Answer (score 2):

We may use `factor` route i.e. after grouping by 'Split_key', `scan` the `first` element of 'Split_key' and use the `integer` converted `factor` column 'label' as index

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(Split_key) %>% 
    mutate(sub_label = scan(text = first(Split_key), what = "", 
      sep="_", quiet = TRUE)[as.integer(factor(label))]) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 × 3
   Split_key label sub_label
   <chr>     <int> <chr>    
 1 A_B_C         7 A        
 2 A_B_C         7 A        
 3 A_B_C         8 B        
 4 A_B_C         8 B        
 5 A_B_C        10 C        
 6 A_B_C        10 C        
 7 D_E_F         2 D        
 8 D_E_F         7 E        
 9 D_E_F        15 F        
10 G_H_I         1 G        
11 G_H_I         2 H        
12 G_H_I         3 I
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Split_key = c("A_B_C", "A_B_C", "A_B_C", "A_B_C", 
"A_B_C", "A_B_C", "D_E_F", "D_E_F", "D_E_F", "G_H_I", "G_H_I", 
"G_H_I"), label = c(7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 15L, 1L, 
2L, 3L), sub_label = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way how you can achieve your goal:
Logic:

1. group by `Split_key`
2. Create grouping variable for `label` using `rleid` function from `data.table`
3. Using some stringr functions to get the aim:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
  group_by(Split_key) %>% 
  mutate(group = rleid(label)) %>%
  mutate(sub_label= str_sub(str_replace_all(Split_key, "[^[:alnum:]]", ""), group, group), .keep="unused")
```

```
 Split_key label sub_label
   <chr>     <int> <chr>    
 1 A_B_C         7 A        
 2 A_B_C         7 A        
 3 A_B_C         8 B        
 4 A_B_C         8 B        
 5 A_B_C        10 C        
 6 A_B_C        10 C        
 7 D_E_F         2 D        
 8 D_E_F         7 E        
 9 D_E_F        15 F        
10 G_H_I         1 G        
11 G_H_I         2 H        
12 G_H_I         3 I
```